# Qt deleteLater causes crash when time is changed

Tags: multithreading, qt

We created a Qt HTTP server derived from QTcpServer.
Each incoming client connection is handled in a new thread like this:

```
    void WebClientThread::run()
    {

        // Configure the web client socket
        m_socket = new QTcpSocket();

       connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
       connect(m_socket, SIGNAL (error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

      // Create the actual web client = worker
      WebClient client(m_socket, m_configuration, m_pEventConnection, m_pThumbnailStreams, m_server, m_macAddress, 0 );

     // Thread event loop
     exec();

     m_pLog->LOG(L_INFO, "Webclient thread finished");
   }
   //
   // Client disconnect
   //
   void WebClientThread::disconnected()
   {
       m_socket->deleteLater();
       exit(0);
   }
```

This code works, but we experienced application crashes when it was executed while the NTP connection of our device kicked in and the system time was corrected from the epoch 01/01/1970 to the current time.
The crash could also be reproduced when running the application and meanwhile changing the system time from a script.

The application runs fine - even when the system time changes on the fly like this:

```
void WebClientThread::run()
{

    // Configure the web client socket
    m_socket = new QTcpSocket();

    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL (error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    // Create the actual web client = worker
    WebClient client(m_socket, m_configuration, m_pEventConnection, m_pThumbnailStreams, m_server, m_macAddress, 0 );

    // Make this thread a loop,
    exec();

    delete m_socket;

    m_pLog->LOG(L_INFO, "Webclient thread finished");

}


//=======================================================================
//
// Client disconnect
//
void WebClientThread::disconnected()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Why would deleteLater() crash the application when the system time is shifted ?

---

Additional information:

OS = embedded linux 3.0.0. Qt = 4.8

The socket is a connection between our Qt web server application and the front end server = lighttpd. Could it be that lighttpd closes the socket when the system time shifts 47 years and the request is still being processed by our web server?

I could reproduce it by sending requests to the server while in parallel running a script that sets date to 1980, 1990 and 2000. It changes once a second.

Comment: can you write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this?Also, please write when do you exactly change the system time to reproduce the bug...

Comment: I wrote a [minimal example](https://pastebin.com/3MHPcEvW), that uses `deleteLater` in a way that's similar to your usage (if I understand it correctly). The example runs fine and produces expected output on both Qt 5.6.2 and Qt 5.9.1 on my windows 7 machine. Are you sure the issue is related to the way you are using `deleteLater`? maybe it is something else in your code that is causing UB...

Comment: Have you `valgrind`-ed it?

Answer (score 0):

This smells of wrong use of Qt threads. I suggest you do not subclass `QThread`, if you call `exec()` from its `run()` method, because it's just too easy to do things wrong way if you do that.

See for example https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage to see how to set up a worker *QObject* for a *QThread*, but the gist of it is, create subclass of `QObject` and put your code there. Then move an instance of that to a `QThread` instance, and connect signals and slots to make things happen.

Another things, you normally shouldn't use threads for Qt Networking, like `QTcpSocket`. Qt is event based and asynchronous, and as long as you just use signals and slots and never block in your slot methods, there is no need for threads, they only complicate things for no benefit. Only if you have time-consuming calculations, or if your program truly needs to utilize multiple CPU cores to achieve good enough performance, only then look into multithreading.